# Cannot view the Streamlit app in chrome browser

Tags: streamlit

when i run:
streamlit run src/frosty_app.py

Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

Network URL: http://172.16.5.4:8501
External URL: http://52.177.56.14:8501

But i cannot access this 2 URL, how to fix it?